# Get local date of an DateTimeOffset .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get the local time of the following DateTimeOffset:

`var date = new DateTimeOffset(2023, 07, 21, 23, 00, 00, TimeSpan.FromHours(5));`

I want the output to be `2023/07/22 04:00 AM` but I only found to transform it to Utc which returns `21/07/2023 18:00 +00:00`

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: `var date = new DateTimeOffset(2023, 07, 21, 23, 00, 00, TimeSpan.FromHours(5)); DateTime localTime = date.ToLocalTime();  `   The ToLocalTime() method will convert the DateTimeOffset date to the local time of the computer where the code is running

Comment: If I do that I will get the oposite I want, it returns 21/07/2023 20:00:00 +02:00 but not the output I am expecting.

Comment: Heve you check your Windows time settings ?

Comment: @LPardoCardona the methods work just fine. `date` already is local at 05:00. If your local time is at `+02:00` you're moving 3 hours back, not 3 hours forward, and definitely not *5* hours forward. `23:00 +05:00` *is* `20:00 +02:00`

Comment: What is your local timezone?

Comment: @LPardoCardona instead of trying to perform offset arithmetic, find out the correct current offsets for your current and destination *timezones*, eg Brazil and Central Europe. Even better, use a library that uses the [IANA timezone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) and  instead of offsets, like NodaTime, and convert between the appropriate timezones, eg `America/Sao_Paulo` and `Europe/Paris`. Offsets change either due to summer time or laws but tzdb names don't- and even if they do, the database contains synonyms and historical rules